# Google Chrome contextMenus API - ContextType "tab" support

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs, contextmenu

Does anyone know if Google is planning on adding support for the "tab" ContextType in the chrome.contextMenus API?

> **tab**
>   Applies when the user context-clicks on a tab (specifically, this refers to the user interface element enabling the user to switch from one browser tab to another, not to the page itself).

It appears Firefox is the only browser that currently supports it [per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/contextMenus/ContextType#Browser_compatibility). Is there a reason that Chrome would purposefully avoid supporting it? I couldn't find any mention of it in the dev status or the google groups.

Comment: Their reason is either there's no one interested in implementing this feature, or the developers are busy with other things, or the intended simplicity of UI.

Comment: The docs on MDN are a mix of what's supported in Chrome & Firefox. What *exactly* the intent of this documentation is not clear. Mozilla will keep adding to it as they support things which are not supported in Chrome, but have not added everything in Chrome that's not supported in Firefox (WebExtensions). Complicating this is that Firefox is both playing catch-up with Chrome wrt. WebExtensions and adding *some* functionality to WebExtensions (functionality available in other types of Firefox extensions, which are **far** more capable than Chrome extensions), but which is unavailable in Chrome.